# DEV C++Crear un atributo arreglo dentro de una clase que reciba objetos de otra clase

Tags: c++

En DEV C++ necesito crear 2 clases, y que una de estas clases tenga un atributo que reciba objetos de la otra clase.. No tengo ni idea sobre como declarar este atributo arreglo, y luego como llenarlo con los objetos de la otra clase.. Si alguien programara algo para guiarme o me explicara como se crean los arreglos para recibir objetos de otra clase le agredeceria de todo corazon :c, saludos y gracias aunque no me ayuden gracias por intentarlo!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que investigaste respecto del pasaje de datos entre clases?

Answer (score 0):

Pues segun lo que entendi de tu pregunta es que quieres usar atributos de otras clases verdad?, puedes hacer herencia la cual trata de dar todos los atributos y metodos de una clase a una clase hija.
Si eso no es lo que buscas entonces talvez lo que necesites es hacer clases amigas la cual trata de que tanto una clase independiente puede acceder a otra clase, aclara un poco mas tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

herencia:

```
class hija: public padre{
};
```

clases amigas:

```
//esto define a que dicha clase o funcion sera amiga de esta
friend void amigo_suma();
```

la funcion amigo_suma() ya puede acceder a los atributos de la clase enlazada